# Can user names be offensive? Handled accordingly?

Tags: discussion

There is (was) an answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2076/12102) where a new user's custom name was more offensive than the deleted answer itself (which was just silly nonsense as far as I could tell).

The problem is that it still shows up in a list of active questions and elsewhere.

Is there a mechanism to handle the user name field if it's deemed offensive?

Also, if an answer is deleted for this reason, should the active questions list still be displaying the icon and user name?

**edit:** removed screenshots (roll back to view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, flag the post with a custom message telling the mods that the username is offensive. Mods can rename the user back to the default id and send them a message.

Comment: In this case, I've already taken action, so no flag necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I've edited the question.

Comment: @uhoh Yep, worked!